# Cakephp Html Helper Structure

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, html-helper

Recently I have shifted from PHP OOPS to CakePHP. I am bit confused with the cakephp Html Helper structure.

Example:

```
  $this -> Html -> css();
```

In the above code, What does `Html` represents? Is it an object or variable, what class and object structure does cakephp maintains and how does it work?

I researched a lot but could not figure out the cakephp class/object structure. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here Html is Object of HtmlHelper class

and css is method of HtmlHelper class , calling by object of class

i am not sure 100% with my answer...and i also have tried but no documantion regarding this available on internet..

for some description please visit this link ...
http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-HtmlHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

1. $this  -  Refer to Current Class means View Class (http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/package-Cake.View.html)
2. Html - Refer to HtmlHelper Class, This is done via HelperCollection Class, See the load Method ( http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-HelperCollection.html#_load)
3. css() - Refer to method css() from HtmlHelper Class